# Is android-5.0-lollipop runtime [ART] compatible with earlier JNI code which works in Dalvik+Kitkat?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-5.0-lollipop, dalvik

I have 6 Android apps in production, available at the Google Store, which apparently *all* fail on Nexus tablets running Android 5.x variants.  All my current tablets are Android Kitkat (4.4.2) or earlier, so for now, I cannot even run a logcat from adb to see what is happening.  Users are reporting none of my apps run on Android 5.0.1 and 5.0.2, and I confirmed it today, with a Nexus 9, at a carrier's retail outlet.  My code uses java and JNI (the native interface).  Java stuff starts ok, but JNI fails.  It looks like others have this problem.  Is there any obvious and elegant way to restore Android 4.4 (Kitkat) operational functionality within the unstable/altered Android 5.0-lollipop?   Specifically:  I need to *disable* the "checkJNI" feature, which is a Dalvik VM feature.  This is done by having a low Android API number in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  I use Android-8 API, but code is built using Android-19 API, and apps work on all 4.x series tablets/phones.  Can I disable "checkJNI" in ART/Lollipop explicitly, as is possible implicitly using Dalvik/Kitcat?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?   Based on the number of reports of broken/failing apps on Android 5.x, there are clearly significant issues. The current workaround seems to be a direct downgrade back to Android 4.4.x.
But if there are some specific show-stopping issues (such as I am apparently dealing with...) re. JNI code migration from Kitkat to Lollipop, a short comment would be most appreciated.  Thanx.

Comment: Maybe you could try your app on a 5.0 emulator? Or at least try a minimal app that uses the jni library that you seem to be having issues with?

Comment: You can run ART on 4.4, too. There are quite a few cases where ART requires more discipline, e.g. with global references and pinned objects.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html